# Ubuntu Server 12.04 Unable to locate package dhcp3-server

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, dhcp-server, packages

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu Server version 12.04 and am trying to install a dhcp server package using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install dhcp3-server
```

However I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dhcp3-server
```

Can someone tell me how to install this package on my server?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is now named `isc-dhcp-server`.  When in doubt just search using the terms `ubuntu package daemon name`.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/isc-dhcp-server

Comment: Thanks man, also can you tell me how to edit the configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

The configuration file you'll want to edit is `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

Also, don't forget to set the adapter in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`